# How to open recent avtivity after app reopen in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How to open recent `activity` after app reopen in android studio
For Example, we create a book application
Then after reopening the app, open the last page where we are

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Demo4">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity2"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What Android Studio got with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Default activity as a launcher activity
`public class Default extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_default);

 SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("IDvalue",0);


    String str = mPrefs.getString("activity", "1");
    if (str.equals("1")) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Default.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (str.equals("2")){

        Intent intent = new Intent(Default.this,MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
public void clickD(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Default.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}`

//In MainActivity while saving preferences use:
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("IDvalue", 0);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString("activity","1");
    editor.apply();
}
public void click(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}`

//In MainActivity2 while saving preferences use:
`
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("IDvalue", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString("activity","2");
    editor.apply();
}
```

}`

Comment: Hope my answer solved your problem. Kindly accept my answer. Don't put yourself answer and accept it. It's a bad practice. I have spent my valuable time to solve your question.

Comment: Its not working, but thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

You can try with launch mode defined in Android manifest. Try with single task. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You use `SharedPreferences`

For Example:

create a String for the last Activity

```
String lastActivity="";
```

Store last Activity

```
    protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    lastActivity = "MainActivity";

    // store activity Name
    final SharedPreferences prefs =  this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE_ACTIVITY",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("activity", lastActivity);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Make a decision:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String myActivity = prefs.getString("activity", "defValue");
    
    if (myActivity.equals(lastActivity)){
        startActivity(new Intent(this , FirstAcitvity.class ));
    }else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this , SecondActivity.class ));
    }
```

refer more [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

### CODE

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String lastActivity = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button one , two , three , four;

    one = findViewById(R.id.one);
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lastActivity = "one";
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity2.class).putExtra("PWD" , "one"));
            saveData();
        }
    });

    two = findViewById(R.id.two);
    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lastActivity = "two";
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity3.class).putExtra("PWD" , "two"));
            saveData();
        }
    });

    three = findViewById(R.id.three);
    three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lastActivity = "three";
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity4.class).putExtra("PWD" , "three"));
            saveData();
        }
    });

    four = findViewById(R.id.four);
    four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lastActivity = "four";
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity5.class).putExtra("PWD" , "four"));
            saveData();
        }
    });



}

private void saveData() {
    String storeMine = lastActivity;
    Log.e("PWD" , storeMine);

    // store activity Name
    final SharedPreferences prefs =  this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE_ACTIVITY",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("activity", storeMine);
    editor.apply();
}

private void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE_ACTIVITY", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String myActivity = prefs.getString("activity", "");

    Log.e("myActivity" , myActivity);

    switch (myActivity){
        case "one":{
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity2.class).putExtra("PWD" , "one"));
            break;
        }
        case "two":{
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity3.class).putExtra("PWD" , "two"));
            break;
        }
        case "three":{
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity4.class).putExtra("PWD" , "three"));
            break;
        }
        case "four":{
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity5.class).putExtra("PWD" , "four"));
            break;
        }


    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    loadData();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have more than two activities?

Comment: @KrishnaGameStudio change ```if``` to ```switch``` condition

Comment: Can you please give a code ,I am trying but not working. I have 10 activities

Comment: @KrishnaGameStudio I update my ```code```